# How do I remove these extra arrows from my output?

Tags: c++

Write a program to Display the following pattern given an input of 10.  Outputs an increase from 1 to 10 the decreases from 10 to 1

+

++

+++

++++

+++++

++++++

+++++++

++++++++

+++++++++

++++++++++

++++++++++

+++++++++

++++++++

+++++++

++++++

+++++

++++

+++

++

+

I tried messing around with endl; but I just cannot seem to figure out why I am getting extra spaces.

```
//System Libraries
#include <iostream>  //Input/Output Library
using namespace std;

//User Libraries

//Global Constants, no Global Variables are allowed
//Math/Physics/Conversions/Higher Dimensions - i.e. PI, e, etc...

//Function Prototypes

//Execution Begins Here!
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    for (int r = 0; r <= 10; r++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (int c = 0; c < r; c++)
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    for (int r = 10; r >= 0; r--)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (int c = 0; c < r; c++)
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output

```
+↵
↵
++↵
↵
+++↵
↵
++++↵
↵
+++++↵
↵
++++++↵
↵
+++++++↵
↵
++++++++↵
↵
+++++++++↵
↵
++++++++++↵
↵
++++++++++↵
↵
+++++++++↵
↵
++++++++↵
↵
+++++++↵
↵
++++++↵
↵
+++++↵
↵
++++↵
↵
+++↵
↵
++↵
↵
+
```

Your Output

```
↵
↵
↵
+↵
↵
++↵
↵
+++↵
↵
++++↵
↵
+++++↵
↵
++++++↵
↵
+++++++↵
↵
++++++++↵
↵
+++++++++↵
↵
++++++++++↵
↵
++++++++++↵
↵
+++++++++↵
↵
++++++++↵
↵
+++++++↵
↵
++++++↵
↵
+++++↵
↵
++++↵
↵
+++↵
↵
++↵
↵
+↵
↵
↵
```

Comment: Because you have `cout << endl` twice in your loops that operate on `r`. You would've easily spotted that if you had used a debugger.

Comment: A sidenote about `endl`: It's a new line and a stream flush and the stream flush can be very expensive. If you only want a new line, let the stream handle when to flush and output the newline character `'\n'`.

Comment: I removed one of the cout << endl from both of the loops yet it did not do anything but removes arrows that I needed.

Comment: Than please define what do you mean by "*why I am getting extra spaces*".

Comment: Looks good to me when I remove the extra `cout << endl;`s. Perhaps you removed the wrong ones?

Comment: the arrows in the program are spaces and I have 3 extra arrows at the beginnning and 3 extra arrows at the end of my output

Comment: Work through it on paper if you can't use a debugger to step through. Your first loop starts, you write a newline. r is 0 so the loop that prints + does not execute, you print a newline. Loop enters the second time, you print a newline, then one + then a newline, loop starts again, etc.

Comment: Oh Smurf. I see your problem. You want two lines, bad edit on my part will fix in a moment, so your real problem is an error in handling the `r == 0` cases.

Comment: If you used a debugger, you would've observed that the very first iteration or the first loop executed `cout << endl` twice, because `r=0` and this no `+` will be displayed in the inner loop. Then, you do `r++` and enter the loop again, which results in the third `cout << endl` being executed.

Comment: I just want to get rid of the three extra arrows at the beginning and end of the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the upper double-loop,...

- First, `c`-loop does not iterate when `r==0` and thus you get double newline characters `↵↵`.
- Next, you get one more `↵` just before `c`-loop when `r==1`.

In the lower double-loop,...

- Finally, `c`-loop does not iterate when `r==0` and thus you get double newline characters `↵↵`.

Thus you should replace the minimum value of `r` to `1` and avoid to output newline character when `r==1` in the lower double-loop as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/veHOIQr8FXkh7WaE)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    for (int r = 1; r <= 10; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < r; ++c)
        {
            std::cout << "+";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    for (int r = 10; r > 0; --r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < r; ++c)
        {
            std::cout << "+";
        }

        if(r != 1){
            std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you change `r >= 1` to `r > 0` in the second `for` loop it's typically a bit easier on the brain.

Comment: @user4581301 thx. Ah, I think so too :).  I fixed that point.

Comment: thank you so much! I understand now that r being = to 0 caused problems with the loop and the placing of endl twice after the first and second part of the loop works perfectly

Comment: Is there a way for me to make it to where the input number of "+" can be changed without having to change what r and c are equal to? For my homework, to get the points I must be able to use different inputs to get different numbers of + but I am not sure how to

Comment: nvm i figured it out. I just subsituted 10 for int i and I got the right answer! thank you though. You really helped me understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time we enter the first loop `r = 0` and for the inner loop `c=0`.
In this case, the condition of the inner loop is not satisfied, so the first state of only two `endl` are executed at the beginning and end of the inner loop.
To correct, you must place in the second loop condition `int c = 0; c <= r; c++`.
in this situation u need to fix condition of first loop to `int r=0; r<10; r++`

u can see this for loops diagram : [for_loop_diagram](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_loop_types.htm)

corrected code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (int c = 0; c <= r; c++)
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    for (int r = 10; r > 0; r--)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (int c = 0; c <= r; c++)
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```